# How can I group/pivot data in Tableau?

Tags: pivot, tableau-api

Suppose I have two columns:

```
A | B
1 | 5 
1 | 6
2 | 16
3 | 7
3 | 9
```

I want to have the following pivot:

```
A | B
1 | 6
2 | 16
3 | 9
```

And perform `AVG()` or other functions on `B` to display the results. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lots of choices:

- If your measure is on the row or columns shelf, then you can just drag an Average line from the Analytics tab
- Or you can turn on grand totals for your columns from the Analysis menu, and then total all using Avg
- Or you can use a table calc by wrapping your measure in a call to **window_avg**() such as `window_avg(max(B))`
- Or you can use an LOD calc such as `{avg({fixed A : max(B)})}` but that is probably overkill

Answer (score 0):

Convert the data type of "A" to string and drag it into dimension as you would like to do group by A. 
[Pull dimensions and measures to rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GFrPZ.jpg) - When you pull A and B in rows, Tableau will automatically do a group by on "A" and do a sum on "B". 
You can perform more operations by creating calculated fields or by double clicking in the measure values box.

```
AVG([B])
```

Click the link to download the twbx file >>
[Group by A tableau packaged workbook](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2KOJRX1srQqYXZqTDhaUjRxb00/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Perhaps, I need to clarify the question, but my aim is to run an aggregated function ``B`` over all the values of ``A`` (after the pivot), thus, the average value I am looking for is (6+16+9)/3 = 10.3

Comment: Got it, In that case - the choices suggested by @alex will work. Windowing/Grand total/LOD.